How can I draw this tiling with text on LaTex?
I need to produce a sort of tiling as in figure. How can I do?



Place nodes. 2. Draw edges. A. Manually. B. Using loops. C. Using a matrix (possibly tikz-cd). Where to you have the problems? What did you already try?


I wouldn't recommend placing nodes individually; that could become complicated.
If it looks like a matrix - just take a TikZ-matrix:

\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
  \DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
nodes={
align=center, inner sep=1pt, 
text height=\ht\strutbox,
text depth=\dp\strutbox,
text width =1.0\ht\strutbox, 
draw=none,% test
},
column sep=0.75ex, 
](m){
   & 0 &      & 0 &       & 0 &      \\ 
q &    & \id &    & \id  &    & \id   \\ 
   & 1 &      & 0 &       & 0 &      \\ 
q &    & \id &    & \id  &    & \id   \\ 
   & 0 &      & 1 &       & 0 &      \\ 
q &    & \id &    & \id  &    & \id   \\ 
   & 1 &      & 1 &       & 1 &      \\ 
q &    & \id &    & \id  &    & \id   \\ 
   & 0 &      & 0 &       & 1 &      \\ 
%1 & 2 & 3   & 4 & 5    & 6 & 7 \\ 
};
% Annotations
\foreach \Col in {2,4,6}{
\foreach \Row in {2,4,...,8}{
\draw[->] ([xshift=-1.25ex]m-\Row-\Col.center) -- +(2.5ex,0);
\draw[<-] ([yshift=-1.25ex]m-\Row-\Col.center) -- +(0,2.5ex);
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


This is another example that can be improved reducing the space between rows and columns (\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}                  and option @{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}). Only the symbol \tosa from STIX package has been used and it is appropriately rotated by 45° (anticlockwise).
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\ts}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{${} \tosa {} $}}
\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows2}       {LS1}{stixsf}   {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{arrows2}     {bold}{LS1}{stixsf}   {b}{it}
\makeatother
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tosa}{\mathrel}{arrows2}{"C2}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}
\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}                 % Remove row spacing
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}  % Remove column spacing
   & 0    &     & 0    &       & 0  &  \\ 
q  & \ts  & \id  & \ts  & \id  &  \ts &  \id \\ 
   & 1  &   & 0  &   &  0 &   \\ 
q  & \ts  & \id  & \ts  & \id  &  \ts &  \id \\  
   & 0  &   & 1  &   &  0 &   \\ 
q  & \ts  & \id  & \ts  & \id  &  \ts &  \id \\  
   & 1 &  & 1 &   & 0  &   \\ 
q  & \ts  & \id  & \ts  & \id  &  \ts &  \id \\  
   & 0 &  & 0 &   & 1  &   
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}


